# Lemma 1.1 from "A course in minimal surfaces" by Colding and Minicozzi.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, stokes-theorem, submanifold, minimal-surfaces

I have just started reading the book "A course in minimal surfaces" by Colding and Minicozzi and I have a question about the proof of the very first **Lemma1.1**.

We have an open domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and a two-form $\omega$ defined on $\Omega \times \mathbb{R}$. We know that $\omega$ is **closed** ($d\omega = 0$). 
Let $u: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function and let $Graph(u)$ be its graph. Let $\Sigma$ be any other surface with the same boundary of $Graph(u)$.

Then in the book there is written that from Stokes' theorem we have
$$
\int_{Graph(u)} \omega = \int_{\Sigma} \omega.
$$

My question is: in order to apply Stokes' Lemma, we should know that $\omega$ is exact, right? We could use Poincaré's Lemma, but we don't know if $\Omega \times \mathbb{R}$ is contractible. Maybe Colding and Minicozzi are tacitly assuming that $\Omega$ is simply connected?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you aware of relation between de Than Cohomology and singular Cohomology? You do not need a contractible domain , only that the domain is homotopy equivalent to a graph.

Comment: I didn't know that. Unfortunately I am not very familiar with cohomology theory. Can you give me some references? 
Thank you @MoisheCohen!

Comment: The best book on de Rham cohomology I know is by Bott and Tu "Differential forms in algebraic topology", http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/botttu.pdf.